# pre_get_posts for exclude category

Tags: pre-get-posts

This code works perfectly

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

But this code does not work at all

```
$caid = "-1";
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', $caid );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/language.variables.scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$caid` is unknown inside the function, unless declared global.

```
$caid = '-1';
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    global $caid;
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', $caid );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

**// Edit**
Do you need the variable outside the function at all? If not, just move it inside the function, then you can ommit the `global`.

[**PHP**: Variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global)

Answer (score 2):

You can as well use [closures in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
$catid = "-1";

$excludeCategory = function ($catid)
{
    return function ($query)
    {
        if (
            $query->is_home() 
            && $query->is_main_query()
        ) {
            $query->set('cat', $catid);
        }
    };
};

add_action('pre_get_posts', $excludeCategory($catid));
```

This is a function returning a function. Therefore you can pass in the catid as a parameter at the time when you register the `pre_get_posts` action.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you want to do this? In the exact given case, that is. Is there some advantage using anonymous functions compared to the intuitive/'old school' way?

Comment: in that example, the benefit is that you can inject the `$catid` variable at the very moment when you call `add_action`. That could be a benefit. When you use a global variable, the problem is that the name is defined and blocked, with this anonymous function example all you pass along is the value in form of a parameter. That's the main difference here (there are other ways to achieve the same in PHP for example with object that have the `__invoke()` method).